# Are Amazon affiliate codes appropriate?

Tags: discussion

If someone asks a question and the legitimate answer is to list books like I did [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50/where-can-i-learn-to-create-my-own-theme/112#112) is it appropriate to include an Amazon affiliate code or not?

Answer (score 4):

Your affiliate code [is stripped away and replaced by a Stack Overflow-specific link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links), so don't worry about it.